# how to use Q promise with underscore filter

Tags: javascript, promise, underscore.js, q

I have found similar questions with different suggestions but I can not get it to work. Some say you can't do it and others give a very long solution to get it working. It is being returned and undefined.

Service

```
 filterSubdivisions: (response) => {
        var arry = [];
        let deferred = Q.defer();
        arry = _.filter(response, (item) => {
            if (item.status === 'A') {
                item.color = 80;
                item.status = 'Active';
                return item
            } else {
                item.color = 255;
                item.status = 'Future';
                return item
            }
        });

        deferred.resolve(arry);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Service Call

```
   AuthService.get().then((result) => {
        SubdivisionService.getSubdivisions(result.userId, result.token)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response)
                    SubdivisionService.filterSubdivisions(response)
            })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res)
                SubdivisionService.loopSubdivisions(res)
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response)
                StorageService.set('Subdivisions', response)
            })
            .then(() => me.onGoHome())
            .catch(error => {
                AlertService.error('subdivisions')
                    .then((error) => ErrorService.post(error))
                    .then(() => me.onGoHome())
            })

    })
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  `filterSubdivisions` returns a promise, yet you are never attaching a `.then` callback to it.  Plus, you are *resolving* that promise right away, so why even used a deferred there in the first place?  Can you explain what you are trying to do and what isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: I just updated the code. And I cant believe I did that! put it in a answer

Comment: So, the issue was never attaching a `.then` to the promise returned from ` filterSubdivisions`?

Comment: yes! I will mark it as answer

Comment: WTH does your `filterSubdivisions` method return a promise? It's not asynchronous! Drop the deferred, `return arry` directly, and you'll be good.

Comment: Your `then` callbacks don't `return` *anything*, so `res` and `response` further down the chain will always be `undefined`.

Comment: well the idea was having to use a timer to make sure the loopService didnt go off before the filter was finished. So I thought this was the way to do it? Its actually working. open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have `filterSubdivisions()` returning a promise, especially if you are resolving it right away instead of doing any sort of asynchronous actions.  Anyway, you are never attaching a `.then()` callback to that promise.

You are resolving it with the filtered array, but never have a callback to get that data.

Comment: I am used to angular handling all the promises, I will do some more reading. thanks!